# How can I generate the API link dynamically with multiple queries in Kotlin using Retrofit 2?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

This is my interface class

```
interface CalorieCalculationInterface {
    @GET("/macrocalculator")
    fun getData(@Query("age") age: Int?, @Query("gender") gender : String?,
                @Query("height") height: Double?, @Query("weight") weight: Double?,
                @Query("activitylevel") activitylevel: Int?, @Query("goal") goal: String?)
    : Call<CalorieCalculationDataResponse>
 }
```

This is my main class where I try to fetch my API with passing age, gender, height, weight, activitylevel and goal. This API gave me calorie in result.

```
private fun getData(ageNum: Int, gender: String, heightNum: Double, weightNum: Double, activityLevel: Int, goalLevel: String) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        try {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://fitness-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader(
                            "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                            "75ef70a478msh3da1c20824c8e15p13575ejsn26185c236f61"
                        ).build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }.build())
                .build()

            val retrofitData = retrofit.create(CalorieCalculationInterface::class.java)

            val response = retrofitData.getData(ageNum, gender, heightNum, weightNum, activityLevel, goalLevel).awaitResponse()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    val calculate = responseBody?.data?.calorie //Here the data is not showing
                    calcuView.text = calculate.toString()

                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }


}
```

I want to generate the api link dynamically

Comment: Please hide your API key

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map` to create query parameters and their respective values parameter as below -

```
interface CalorieCalculationInterface {
            @GET("/macrocalculator")
            fun getData(@QueryMap queries: Map<String, Any>): Call<CalorieCalculationDataResponse>
        }
    
    val apiService = retrofit.create(CalorieCalculationInterface::class.java)

    val queries = HashMap<String, Any>()
    queries["age"] = 25
    queries["gender"] = "male"
    queries["height"] = 180.0
    queries["weight"] = 75.0
    queries["activitylevel"] = 2
    queries["goal"] = "lose"
    
    val call = apiService.getData(queries)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vinay but it also didn't work

Comment: Basically this is the way for creating the request url using Hashmap. So whats issue you facing?